# How do I add a full page transition? (See description)

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

Im creating a website with HTML5 and CSS3 and i was thinking about having a front page with a background image only and the option to enter the website with an arrow or 'enter to site' button.

But instead of clicking the button and it takes you to another html file/new site (as when you click a link in a standard navigation) i want it to fade in  from the bottom - like the 'fade from bottom' option here http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ - to a new page (ordinary front page) within the same html document, so the visiter doesnt have to load a new page.

Anyone?

(PS. i tried the function in the link above, but could not get it to work)

Comment: Before trying to develop this, really think this over. Is it really useful to have an "Enter this site" button? Do you need this? Most of the time, you do not need things like this.

Comment: If you have tried it, what exactly isn't working?  Can you put your code in jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 1):

you need Modernizr, pagetransitions.js and animations.css to get that same efect if you only need 'fade from bottom' you can use this modified pagetransitions.js

```
var PageTransitions = (function() {

    var $main = $( '#pt-main' ),
            $pages = $main.children( 'div.pt-page' ),
            $iterate = $( '#iterateEffects' ),
            animcursor = 1,
            pagesCount = $pages.length,
            current = 0,
            isAnimating = false,
            endCurrPage = false,
            endNextPage = false,
            animEndEventNames = {
                    'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                    'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
                    'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
                    'animation' : 'animationend'
            },
            animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
            // support css animations
            support = Modernizr.cssanimations;

    function init() {
            $pages.each( function() {
                    var $page = $( this );
                    $page.data( 'originalClassList', $page.attr( 'class' ) );
            } );
            $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'pt-page-current' );
            $iterate.on( 'click', function() {
                    if( isAnimating ) {
                            return false;
                    }
                    nextPage( animcursor );
                    ++animcursor;
            } );
    }

    function nextPage(options ) {
            var animation = (options.animation) ? options.animation : options;
            if( isAnimating ) {
                    return false;
            }
            isAnimating = true;
            var $currPage = $pages.eq( current );
            if(options.showPage){
                    if( options.showPage < pagesCount - 1 ) {
                            current = options.showPage;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
            }
            else{
                    if( current < pagesCount - 1 ) {
                            ++current;
                    }
                    else {
                         return false;
                    }
            }
            var $nextPage = $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'pt-page-current' ),
                    outClass = '', inClass = '';
              outClass = 'pt-page-fade';
              inClass = 'pt-page-moveFromBottom pt-page-ontop';
            $currPage.addClass( outClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
                    $currPage.off( animEndEventName );
                    endCurrPage = true;
                    if( endNextPage ) {
                            onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
                    }
            } );
            $nextPage.addClass( inClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
                    $nextPage.off( animEndEventName );
                    endNextPage = true;
                    if( endCurrPage ) {
                            onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
                    }
            } );
            if( !support ) {
                    onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
            }

    }

    function onEndAnimation( $outpage, $inpage ) {
            endCurrPage = false;
            endNextPage = false;
            resetPage( $outpage, $inpage );
            isAnimating = false;
    }

    function resetPage( $outpage, $inpage ) {
            $outpage.attr( 'class', $outpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) );
            $inpage.attr( 'class', $inpage.data( 'originalClassList' ) + ' pt-page-current' );
    }
    init();
    return { 
            init : init,
            nextPage : nextPage,
    };

})();
```

CSS

```
/* move from / to  */
.pt-page-moveFromBottom {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom .6s ease both;
    -moz-animation: moveFromBottom .6s ease both;
    animation: moveFromBottom .6s ease both;
}
/* fade */
.pt-page-fade {
    -webkit-animation: fade .7s ease both;
    -moz-animation: fade .7s ease both;
    animation: fade .7s ease both;
}

/* move from / to  */
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from { transform: translateY(100%); }
}

/* fade */

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    to { opacity: 0.3; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
    to { opacity: 0.3; }
}
@keyframes fade {
    to { opacity: 0.3; }
}

*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
body, html { font-size: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

/* Clearfix hack by Nicolas Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
.pt-perspective {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
    -moz-perspective: 1200px;
    perspective: 1200px;
}

.pt-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.pt-page-current,
.no-js .pt-page {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}

.no-js body {
    overflow: auto;
}

.pt-page-ontop {
    z-index: 999;
}

.pt-page-1 {
    background: #0ac2d2;
}

.pt-page-2 {
    background: #7bb7fa;
}

.no-js .pt-triggers {
    display: none;
}
```

html

```
<div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective">
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-1">     
         <h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1>
         <div class="pt-triggers">
             <button id="iterateEffects" class="pt-touch-button">Show next page transition</button>                      
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-2">
        <h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tjgy/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. it seems to work in your jsfiddle - but somehow it wont work for me? 

Here's mine: http://jsfiddle.net/userx007/n9gBJ/

It just displays a grey background? why?

Also is it possible to style the button that generates the transition? maybe replace it with an image or rather an icon using ex. fontawesome?

Comment: you need to add Modernizr i have the contents of modernizr.custom.js in the jsfiddle and yes it is posible to style the button or replace it with other element in the jsfiddle i just copy the button from [https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions](https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions) and remove the extra css

Comment: I've tried everything - and still cant get it to work.. Arrg.. 

Ok let me tell you what i did.. I have my html code - i link it to a js file with the modernizr code from your jsfiddle - then i link the html code to another js file with the other javascript from your jsfiddle - then i link my html with a css file that contains your css code from jsfiddle.. and somehow it still doesnt work? only displaying a grey screen.. 

I hope you're able to tell me what im doing wrong --my jsfiddle file: http://jsfiddle.net/userx007/ufR5R/

Comment: you forgot to add jquery on Frameworks & Extensions in the jsfiddle